# Android-Populate a spinner using asynctask by json response from the server (NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ..)

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

I am trying to populate a Spinner from a JSON response using an async task. I am getting the JSON object as a server response and the response is correct. Here it is.
`[{"category_id":1,"category_name":"History"},{"category_id":2,"category_name":"Sports"},{"category_id":3,"category_name":"Science"},{"category_id":4,"category_name":"gg"}]`

I am calling an asynctask on the `View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstranceState)`

But I am getting a 'null object reference error' on HomeFragment activity launch.

Here is my SpinnerAdapter.class.

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.quizapp.model.Category;

import java.util.List;

public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private Context context;

public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<Category> list){
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.categoryList = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return categoryList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return (Category)categoryList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder spinnerHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        spinnerHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_spinner_text_layout, parent,false);
        spinnerHolder.spinnerItemList = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.catsSpinnerText);
        convertView.setTag(spinnerHolder);
    }else {
        spinnerHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    spinnerHolder.spinnerItemList.setText(categoryList.get(position).getCatName());
    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView spinnerItemList;
}
```

}

This is the AsyncTask for populating the Spinner written in the HomeFragment.class.

```
public class CategoryLoadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Category[]> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading Game", "Please wait..");
    }

    @Override
    protected Category[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String json ="";
        Category[] categories = null;
        try {
            json = new RestClient().doGet(getString(R.string.category_url));
            categories = new Gson().fromJson(json, Category[].class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return categories;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Category[] categories){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (categories != null){
            SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(context, Arrays.asList(categories));
            catsSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error log.

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.quizapp, PID: 2381
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.quizapp.HomeFragment$CategoryLoadAsyncTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:90)
                      at com.example.quizapp.HomeFragment$CategoryLoadAsyncTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:64)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)`

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: It looks like that you forgot the initialize catsSpinner variable. Can you share the related part from your HomeFragment or can you check your code? As you know, the best way to find views in your fragment is onViewCreated callback. Let me know when you update question.

Comment: @MetehanToksoy Thank you !! That was the problem. I have commented out it by mistake.

Comment: You're welcome. I just post this comment as an answer to close this question. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you forgot the initialize ***catsSpinner*** variable. Can you share the related part from your HomeFragment or can you check your code? As you know, the best way to find views in your fragment is onViewCreated callback. Let me know when you update question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(context, Arrays.asList(categories));
```

With this

```
SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(GetActivity(), Arrays.asList(categories));
```

Comment: Send the Error Log